# Girsanov Theorem

Tags: stochastic-processes

I am interested in understanding Kallenberg's Proof of Girsanov's theorem.

The Theorem says: If $Q=Z_{t}P$ and $Q$,$P$ are probability measures and $Z$ is a.s. continuous, then for all local P-martingale $X -  X':=X-Z^{-1}[X,Z]$ is a local $Q$-martingale.

I do not get the parts which say that $-[X,Z]+[X',Z]=0$ and that $X'Z$ is a $Q$-martingale because of $X'Z-(X'Z)_{0}=X'*M+Z*m$, where $[.,.]$ is the quadratic covariation, and $X'*Z$ is a stochastic integral.

Comment: This might be a better fit on math.SE since there is not much of statistics in the question.